# Error While Updating Symfony2 Project

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to inject a Google Analytics tracking number into all my Symfony2 views so I used the instructions here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html using this method:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        ga_tracking: "%ga_tracking%"
```

And then I added my tracking number to parameters.yml

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    ga_tracking: UA-xxxxx-x
```

And everything works perfectly but as soon as I do a `composer.phar update` or install I get the following message:

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "ga_tracking".

And the ga_tracking line in my parameters.yml file gets erased (along with a couple other variables I've defined using the same process).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add ga_tracking (and your other variables) to parameters.yml.dist and give them a null or default value.  Update will then prompt you for values.

Answer (score 1):

The `parameters.yml` file is edited by Composer upon update, there's actually a comment about this at the top of the file...

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
```

If you want to store additional parameters, store them elsewhere. In your `config.yml`, add a custom parameters file to your current imports :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: my_parameters.yml } # Your custom file.
    - { resource: security.yml }
```

Once you've made the edit, add your variables/parameters into a `my_parameters.yml` file instead. This one should be left untouched when updating. Don't forget to specify the `parameters` group in your custom file as well :

**my_parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    ga_tracking: "Your-tracking-code"
    #ga_tracking: "%ga_tracking%"
```